# How to get textbox value in gridview on clicking edit button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Iam new to asp.net and I have been trying the above question for some time without any success. here's my code in the roweditevent

```
 GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
 int newindex = e.NewEditIndex;
 TextBox NAME = GridView1.Rows[newindex].FindControl("txtboxname") as TextBox;
 string gridupdat = NAME.Text;
```

But on debugging I always get null reference there.

this is my row update code and it's working fine

```
Label ID = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ID") as Label;
    TextBox NAME = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtboxname") as TextBox;
    DropDownList STATUS = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("dropdownstatus") as DropDownList;
    string string1 = NAME.Text;
    if (fetchmail(string1, labelgrid999) == true)
    {
        string updatquery = string.Format("UPDATE Compliance_Tracker.dbo.verificationMaster SET NAME='{0}',STATUS='{1}' WHERE ID = {2}", NAME.Text, STATUS.Text, Convert.ToInt32(ID.Text));
        string dupquery = "select COUNT(*) from Compliance_Tracker.dbo.verificationMaster where Compliance_Tracker.dbo.verificationMaster.NAME = '" + NAME.Text + "';";
        if (obj4.isDuplicate(dupquery) == false )
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            string populatequery = updatquery + ";select NAME,(case when STATUS='1' then 'Active' when STATUS='0'then 'Inactive' ELSE 'UNKNOWN' END)as STATUS,ID from Compliance_Tracker.dbo.verificationMaster;";
            obj4.BindGridData(populatequery, GridView1);
        }
        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + "Username already exists" + "');", true);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        string myStringVariable = "Please enter valid username";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + myStringVariable + "');", true);
    }
```

Comment: I am guessing your txtboxname is not being found. On what line do you get the exception?

Comment: but i have used the same code in the row update event and it is working fine

Comment: So `Name` does not get found. Are you sure the txtboxname is actually correct?

Comment: yep shall i give the row update code too

Comment: please, if anyone can find what's the problem just post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i do when I try to fetch the data from textbox on Edit Button click:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Button ID="BtnEdit" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="updateData" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Price">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox ID="TxtPriceEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Product_Price") %>' Width="120px"></asp:TextBox>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code Behind :

```
protected void GrdDataEdit_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "updateData")
    {
        // This will give you the ID of the record you are passing in the CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'  
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); 

        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
        TextBox price = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TxtPriceEdit");
    }
}
```

Comment: so we just can't get the value inside the GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e) event

Comment: may be there would be few other ways, but this is what I do, to get my job done.

Comment: its ok, it all about helping, Reputation don't count. I'm Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

On row databound event track the row state and make the necessary calls to acquire the reference of the required control calling `FindControl()` on the `GridViewRow` object.

```
protected void gvMaint_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
    {
        TextBox txtFreqMiles = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtFreqMiles");

        // At this point, you can change the value as normal
        txtFreqMiles.Text = "some new text";
    }
}
```

Code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21580715/145682)

Comment: this code runs when you click on the edit button on a template field column which has a textbox column, and, the grid is being databind-ed in edit mode. The scenario in other words is, you want to populate the textbox with a default value, you'd do something like this. This was entirely different from your recently stated purpose, before I answered the question.

Comment: ok, but my question was to get the value in the gridview textbox which I got it now

Comment: @user3789152 Ok. No problems. Just make sure next time you post a question, give accurate details to help reproduce the problem or help other people better understand quickly. Welcome to SO, and happy programming. :)

Answer (score 0):

The GridViewEventArgs has the index of the row being edited. It doesn't look like you are using the index from the event args. Try this:

```
protected void edit(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)         
{

    string gridupdat = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[0].Text;
    // where Cells[0] = the index of your "txtboxname" column
}
```

Comment: but, iam using the index from eventargs as you can see in my code .

Comment: You are using e.RowIndex NOT e.NewEditIndex

Comment: the problem is in the edit code and  in that portion ,Iam using the e.neweditindex

Comment: @SQL.NETWarrior: first line.